# joomla get page body

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

How to do in joomla:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

using php. I want to get page body by for example menu id, or menu link.
I know that for module I can use:

```
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_module');
$result = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

But what about content

Comment: Am I right in assuming you want to display a component on an external website?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? If I am understanding your questions correctly, there is no corresponding function that does the same thing for a component. The closes you will probably come is using the tmpl=component parameter.

Comment: You don't need component output for menu item id or menu link. Can you specify exactly what you need so we could find a solution?